# How to get a geo location and show to the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I have been trying to get a location address from a text box then get the latitude and longitude from the address and show the nearest train station from the address.

I can get the latitude and longitude of an address
I also can show the nearest train stations from a specific latitude and longitude.

My problem is when I try to get the latitude and longitude form an address and put the address latitude and longitude to show the nearest train station, I failed.

Please find my code below(problem is in alert-)-

```
function initialize() {

        // start
        var latitude;
        var longitude;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                alert(longitude);

            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });

        alert(longitude);

        var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8176108, 145.0422631);

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: pyrmont,
            zoom: 15
        });

        var request = {
            location: pyrmont,
            radius: 1000,
            types: ['train_station', 'bus_station', 'subway_station',   'transit_station']
        };
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);  

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `geocoder.geocode` runs asynchronously, you'll not be able to access the results before the callback has been called, so you should invoke the following (nearbySearch) in the callback.

Another problem: currently you'll not be able to geocode/search again without creating a new map(of course you may always create a new map by calling `initialize` again, but this will result in bad performance and will also increase the map-loads...which are limited).

a solution which separates the map-creation from the geocoding/search(wraps the address-field into a form, the geocoding/search will be invoked when the form will be submitted)

```js
function initialize() {

  "use strict";
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8176108, 145.0422631),
      zoom: 1
    }),
    field = document.getElementById('address'),
    form = field.form,
    marker = new google.maps.Marker(),
    info = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
    //I use this object later to hide previously added markers 
    mvc = new google.maps.MVCObject(),
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  //use the field as control when you want to    
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(form);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(info, 'open', this);
  });

  //this will open the infowindow for a clicked marker
  //the infowindow-content will be retrieved from the 
  //content-property of the marker
  google.maps.event.addListener(info, 'open', function(marker) {
    this.setContent(marker.get('content'));
    this.open(marker.getMap(), marker);
  });

  marker.bindTo('map', mvc, 'map');

  //this separates the geocoding/places-search from the map-creation
  //it will be executed when the form will be submitted
  //(e.g. by hitting ENTER in the address-field) 
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(form, 'submit', function(e) {
    if (e) e.preventDefault();

    //this hides all markers and the infowindow
    mvc.set('map', null);

    if (field.value.match(/\S+/)) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': field.value
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          mvc.set('map', map);
          if (results[0].geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          }

          marker.setValues({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            content: results[0].formatted_address
          });


          service.nearbySearch({
            location: results[0].geometry.location,
            radius: 1000,
            types: ['train_station', 'bus_station', 'subway_station', 'transit_station']
          }, function(places, status) {

            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

              //will be used later to set the viewport
              //so that it contains all markers
              var b = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

              places.forEach(function(place, i) {

                var m = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: place.geometry.location,
                  icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png',
                  content: place.name
                });

                b.extend(place.geometry.location);
                m.bindTo('map', mvc, 'map');

                google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'map_changed', function() {
                  if (!this.getMap()) this.unbindAll();
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function() {
                  google.maps.event.trigger(info, 'open', this);
                });


              });

              if (places.length > 1) {
                map.fitBounds(b);
              }
            } else {
              alert('NearbySearch was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }

          });
        } else {
          alert('Geocoding was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
  //trigger form-submit for the initial search 
  google.maps.event.trigger(form, 'submit');

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#address {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&v=3">
</script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<form>
  <input id="address" value="21 Elphin Grove, Hawthorn VIC 3122, Australia" placeholder="insert an address and hit ENTER" title="insert an address and hit ENTER"/>
</form>
```